# WSO2 API manager failing to create new api with MySql

Tags: mysql, wso2-api-manager

I have a new install of wso2 api manager v1.10.0. When using the default master-datasources.xml that uses the h2 database it works fine. I can click on the 'Deploy Sample API' button and the CalculatorAPI sample gets created properly. However, when I change master-datasources.xml to use MySql then trying to create the sample Calculator API hangs (the UI hangs at "Please Wait"). The CalculatorAPI is created but is not Published and the lifecycle cannot be changed to Published. The only change I made was to master-datasources.xml.

MySql and wso2AM are installed locally on Ubuntu Linux.

The data source configs for MySql I am using are:

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb</url>
           <username>regadmin</username>
           <password>regadmin</password>
           <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
           <maxActive>80</maxActive>
           <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
           <minIdle>5</minIdle>
           <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
           <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
           <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
        <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WSO2AM_DB</url>
                <username>regadmin</username>
                <password>regadmin</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
        <maxActive>80</maxActive>
        <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
        <minIdle>5</minIdle>
        <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
        <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
        <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

I ran the following commands in MySql to apply privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON regdb.* TO regadmin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "regadmin";
GRANT ALL ON WSO2AM_DB.* TO regadmin@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "regadmin";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I started api manager with -Dsetup and it did create tables under both regdb and WSO2AM_DB.

The MySql jdbc driver is in repository/components/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar.

I checked all the logs and there are no errors. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I also tried using the MySql url of:<url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WSO2CARBON_DB?autoReconnect=true&amp;relaxAutoCommit=true</url> and it made no difference.

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: MySql version is: Server version: 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: is there any errors printed on wso2carbon.log file?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to follow this documentation. And rather using -Dsetup try manually

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Setting+up+MySQL

Comment: I dropped the databases and re-created them using the scripts from wso2 and the problem is the same. The CalculatorAPI gets created by the lifecycle is CREATED and cannot be published. Change from MySql to H2 and it works properly.

Comment: There are no errors in any of the logs or the console. I set log4j to DEBUG.

Comment: Is it possible to create a new API and publish?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same scenario using wso2 API manager 1.10 with MySQL but it works for me.

If you are still getting this error

1. Delete the API and disconnect your wifi or broadband connection for a while and try.
2. If you can see the API in CREATED mode. click on the API and go to lifecycle tab and change the status to PUBLISHED.

Comment: Well, I disconnected from my network and tried again and now it works. Why? Very odd. Anyway, thanks for the assistance. BTW, when it did not work the api was getting created. However, in the Lifecycle tab the Publish button was inactive and clicking on it did nothing at all.

Comment: Good. We are investigating about the  network problem. for now as a workaround replace ${carbon.local.ip} with localhost in your apimanager.xml file.